# Scroll bar not visible in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, scrollbar

I have developed a chrome extension which is supposed to have a scroll bar if the content in the popup is more than the specified height to the body of popup .

I am adding the contents of my popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <title>Compare Hatke</title>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='popup.js'>
    </script>
    <style>
      body {
        min-width:357px;
        min-height: 500px;
        overflow-x:hidden;
        overflow-y:auto;
      }

      img {
        margin:5px;
        border:2px solid black;
        vertical-align:middle;
        width:75px;
        height:75px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    Extension developed by Prashant Singh
  </body>
</html>
```

Also the JS which is injecting data to the popup file

```
var len = currentArray.length;
  var string = "";

  for(i=0;i<len;i++){
    if(tab.id==currentArray[i].tabID){
     string += "<img src='" + currentArray[i].image + "' height='20px' max-width='100px'> " + currentArray[i].prod +"<br>";
    }
  }
  document.write(string);
```

What could be the possible issue ? I am not getting scroll bar even if the data to be shown is much much greater that can be shown in one view.

Any explanation would be appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: Why -1 ? Either explain the issue or tell me at least why a -1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added a div in the popup.html page

```
<body>
    <div id='showData'>
    Extension developed by Prashant Singh
  </div>
  </body>
```

And replaced `document.write` by `document.getElementById('showData').innerHTML` and it worked in a flash. Any explanation. Why previous one was not working ?